# ServiceStack Razor ContentPage Works in Debug but not deployed

Tags: razor, servicestack

I am trying a very simple contentpage at ~/View.cshtml that consists of

```
@inherits ViewPage
﻿    @{
       Layout = "SimpleLayout";
       ViewBag.Title = "Title";
}
<div id="content-page">
<p>Test</p>
</div>
```

at ~/Views/Shared/SimpleLayout.cshtml is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Layout</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="content">
     @RenderBody()
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In debug mode it works fine, but on deploy it then shows

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0146: Circular base class dependency
>   involving 'RazorOutput.ViewPage' and 'RazorOutput.ViewPage'

I'm trying to follow the RockStars example as closely as possible, so don't have an idea of what's wrong. My service views work fine.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Update**

When the name of the page is changed (e.g. NewPage.cshtml) then it will not work in Debug either, throwing the same exception.

Comment: Do you have a Github repository or other means to share your project's code? Using RazorRockstar example I have not seen issues compiling Views with a 'parent Layout' in Debug and Release configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Web.Config`, make sure that you have:

```
<compilation debug="false">
```

I was getting the same error, and this fixed it.

Comment: This seems to have fixed it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `compilation debug="false"` as suggested above did not work for me.

I was having the same error running locally in IIS Express and found that if I added this to the web.config it would work:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="webPages:Enabled" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

I found that setting in ServiceStack's RazorRockstar sample, after comparing it line by line with my own project to see why mine wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving similar compilation errors when trying to render Razor pages. Check that your website's `AppHost` is inheriting from `AppHostBase` and not `AppHostHttpListenerBase`.

Comment: Nice thought, but this isn't it. I'll get the code up this weekend.